# Reading text file with multiple characters and integers in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a text file that contains alphabets, characters (comma, semicolon,space,asterisk etc.) and floating point numbers.How can I read this text file in MATALAB ans store it in an array/structure?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the [textscan](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) function.

Provided your text file is organized into columns of values sharing the same format, textscan will allow you to read each column with the appropriate conversion specifier.

Your data will be stored into a cell array.

Comment: The text file is quite disorganized

Comment: @Karthik P, we don't know what the text file is ,but you can do what Sheldon answered or you can try 'fgets' function for reading , please see[Here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgets.html) or [Here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/serial.fgets.html)